# Creating a initial / first boot viewcontroller with NSUserDefaults in storybord

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

So im trying to skip my first viewcontroller if a NSUserDefaults key is found. But its not working. Is it smart to use a Segue for this? Im new to storybord.

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Im using this code in the viewDidLoad of the first VC:

```
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {

        NSLog(@"not first launch");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToNewTrackTraceVC" sender:self];


    }else{
        NSLog(@"First launch");
    }

    NSLog(@"initialViewController loaded");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to update the `NSUserDefault` after the first launch.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{

    NSLog(@"not first launch");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToNewTrackTraceVC" sender:self];


}
else
{
    NSLog(@"First launch");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
}
```

Comment: Nah the NSUserDefault is updated ones the actions on the initial viewcontroller are finished by the user. Isnt there a way to change the initial scene in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform a segue from viewDidLoad, because the controller whose class that code is in, is about to be presented itself, and its view has not been added to the window hierarchy yet. You should put the code in viewDidAppearAnimated:. IF you don't want to see that segue happening, then uncheck the "Animates" box for the segue in the storyboard (that box is available for modal transitions, I don't think it is for a push).